# Getting GPS data?

Tags: android, gps

Inside

```
public class IAmHere extends Activity implements LocationListener {
```

i have

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

and

inside

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.iamhere);
```

i have

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    
    List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);  

    /* Loop over the array backwards, and if you get an accurate location, then break out the loop*/  
     Location l = null;  

    for (int i=providers.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {  
            l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));  
            if (l != null) break;  
        }  

      double[] gps = new double[2];  
      if (l != null) {  
          gps[0] = l.getLatitude();  
          gps[1] = l.getLongitude();  
      }  

      gpsString = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gpsString);

  String Data = ""; 
  String koordinata1 = Double.toString(gps[0]);
  String koordinata2 = Double.toString(gps[1]);
  Data = Data + koordinata1 + " | " + koordinata2 + "\n";
  gpsString.setText(String.valueOf(Data));
```

but seems it's not working? Why? I mean even emulator doesn't want to send GPS data - When I click "send" via UI or console, nothing happens...?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you implemented `LocationListener` on `IAmHere`, then did nothing with that interface.

Second, you are calling `getLastKnownLocation()`, but you are doing nothing to trigger Android to start collection location data on any provider.

These two problems are related.

Location services are off until something registers to get location data from them. Typically, this is via `requestLocationUpdates()` on `LocationManager`...which uses the `LocationListener` interface you implemented.

The recipe for using `LocationManager` is:

1. Register a `LocationListener` via `requestLocationUpdates()`
2. Unregister the `LocationListener` sometime (e.g., `onDestroy()`), so that you do not leak memory
3. When location fixes come into `onLocationChanged()`, do something useful

[Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherPlus/) that uses `LocationManager` and `LocationListener` in this fashion.

Comment: I did exactly this but I keep getting memory leaks whenever I exit and re-launch my activity (i.e. it consumes an increasing number of memory until crash). Is there anything else that needs to be done to prevent this?

Comment: @kelmer: Use MAT to determine where you are leaking.

Comment: I did't use MAT but if I comment the line  mgr.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, onLocationChange); I am not leaking anymore (found out about it through logCat GC_CONCURRENT lines)